# Is there a word that describes how sonic moves by spinning?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> Sonic the hedgehog crossed the streets at lightning speed by ___
> across the street.

I am not sure if spinning is the word, because it doesn't exactly mean "rolling one's body over and over again and in a fast manner", so I am wondering what's the right word or phrase to convey this meaning.

Comment: That definition is a bit limited. A top spins about a vertical axis. I can't think of a better word for Sonic's movement.

Comment: Rolling. Or, wheeling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Spinning" is fine for a general description.  In the game, this move is called a "[Spin dash](https://sonic.fandom.com/wiki/Spin_Dash)".  So if you are talking about the game you could say  "spin-dashing".